# How does Rails decide when to rewrite a URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to learn how the routing/URL writing mechanisms work. I'm in Rails 2.3 but most of the modules are the same in Rails 3.

Anyway, rails generates helpers for all your routes of the format resource_path, and resource_url.

When you call these helpers with no arguments `root_path()`, the operations are different than when you call them with extra arguments `root_path(:random_param=>"myquery")`. When you pass options to the _path helper, Rails triggers the UrlRewriter#rewrite method, and does a much more comprehensive process.

I'm trying to find out where and how this trigger to the UrlRewriter happens? Does rails actually store the 'default' no-params url as a string somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Reverse engineering the _path helper method is very difficult because so much of it is dynamically generated. The method is not simple, here is what it looks like after all is said and done for a :posts resource.

```
def posts_path(*args)  
  users_url(*args)
   args.compact! 

    return "#{ActionController::Base.relative_url_root if ActionController::Base.relative_url_root}/posts" if 
             (!defined?(default_url_options) || default_url_options.blank?) && 
             (!defined?(controller.default_url_options) || controller.default_url_options.blank?) && 
             defined?(request) && request && args.size == 0

    return "#{ActionController::Base.relative_url_root if ActionController::Base.relative_url_root}/posts#{'?' + args.last.to_query unless args.last.empty?}" if 
          (!defined?(default_url_options) || default_url_options.blank?) && 
          (!defined?(controller.default_url_options) || controller.default_url_options.blank?) && 
          defined?(request) && request && args.size == 2 && !args.last.has_key?(:anchor) && 
          !args.last.has_key?(:params) && !args.last.has_key?(:only_path) && 
          !args.last.has_key?(:host) && !args.last.has_key?(:protocol) && !args.last.has_key?(:port) && 
          !args.last.has_key?(:trailing_slash) && !args.last.has_key?(:skip_relative_url_root) && !args.last.has_key?(:subdomain)

     opts = if args.empty? || Hash === args.first   
               args.first || {}                                                          
            else                                                                        
               options = args.extract_options!                                           
               args = args.zip([:format]).inject({}) do |h, (v, k)|  
                 h[k] = v                                                                
                 h                                                                       
               end                                                                       
               options.merge(args)                                                       
            end 

            url_for(hash_for_posts_path(opts))                         
          end
```

The routes module tries aggressively to optimize route resolution. The 'return' statements are various conditions built dynamically by rails or user libraries/gems to resolve a route without having to go through the `url_for()` method at the end. BTW this is ActionController#Base.url_for.

As the first 'return' statement shows, this method will return "/posts" if args.size == 0, meaning when the method is called with no arguments i.e. `posts_path()`. If none of the return statements are successful then a UrlRewrite is initated using url_for.

If you have a lot of logic that depends on url_for being called (which was my case) then you need to reconsider. Because the 'return' conditions are dynamically generated, there is no way to reliably predict if the method will return a default path or try to perform a rewrite.

If anyone has more info to add to this answer, please edit.